# Correct way to add robots.txt and hide it?

Tags: authentication, robots.txt

I have a secret folder on my hosting, which may not be seen by visitors. I've added a `robots.txt` to `htdocs`:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /super-private/
```

However, if a visitor goes to http://example.com/robots.txt, he can see the name of the private folder. Is there anything to be done? Htaccess maybe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`robots.txt` is not the solution here. All it does is tell things like search engine spiders that a particular URL should not be indexed; it doesn't prevent access.

Put a `.htaccess` file in `super-private` containing the following:

```
Deny From All
```

Once you've done this, there's no need for `robots.txt`, as it'll be inaccessible anyway. If you want to allow access to certain people, then look into [authentication with `.htaccess`](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htaccess-authentication/).

Answer (score 2):

Don't mention this private folder in `robots.txt`. Then simply disallow the access to it with `.htaccess`:

```
deny from all
```

Also if there are no links to this `super-private` folder in the other pages robots should never know if its existence but disallowing the access is a good thing to do if this folder should never be directly accessed from clients.